# What is a simple way to express Class vs Instance?

Tags: colloquialisms, concept

In object-oriented programming, the concepts of "class" vs "instance" exist. The "class" defines the properties of the object (its behavior and attributes), while the "instance" is a specific example of the class. The process of creating an instance of a class is referred to "instantiation".

Examples of this concept can also be frequently observed outside of computer programming. Specifically, I am interested in this concept in the context of e-commerce. Take two online marketplace platforms, Amazon and eBay. Simplistically, Amazon is a marketplace operated by suppliers of new goods, while eBay is a P2P marketplace for used goods.

As such, on Amazon I care about the "class" of item I am buying, while on eBay I care about the "instance". This is because on Amazon, I can generally assume that the differences between the instances of each item within the same class are insignificant, while on eBay I care about the condition and other attributes of the exact instance of the item I am buying.

Consumers seem to generally understand this distinction when using Amazon and eBay, yet this seems to come more implicitly from the context created by the usage pattern of the platform rather than through an explicit explanation. In a vacuum, this creates ambiguity; for example, take a website that advertises the ability to "Search for iPhones for sale".  Based on this phrase alone, it is unclear to the user whether performing a search will result in being shown classes of iPhones for sale, or instances of iPhones for sale.

The best colloquial terminology to represent "class" vs "instance" in this context that I have been able to come up with are the terms "model" vs "listing" respectively. However, it is unclear to me how universally understood such terminology is, especially given how there does not seem to be an explicit distinction between the two concepts in the mind of the average consumer.

Perhaps another alternative is to express this in terms of "new" vs "used". Generally speaking, buyers are interested in the class when buying new, and the instance when buying used. However, this approach is limited; it is also reasonable to be interested in instances of new items, or classes of used items.

As such, both aforementioned ideas seem insufficient to me.

For each case, is there a simple, concise and unambiguous way to describe whether it is a class or instance that is being offered? Specifically, the phrases I am looking to express concisely are "search for classes of iPhones for sale", and "search for instances of iPhones for sale".

Comment: Not perfect, but maybe “retail” and “individual listing”??

Comment: Some sellers may advertise a single iPhone for sale, sell it, then leave the ad in place to sell another iPhone. For real estate the listings are normally "instances" because the particular property is identified. Antiques and similar items likewise. For iPhones the "instance" listing would need to specify *which* one, perhaps by giving a serial number.

Comment: A well expressed question to which I find no convincing general answer. To me the classes are types and the instances are items.

Comment: @Jim I think this is very similar to the idea of "model" vs "listing" that I was describing. Yet as I said, I'm not sure if it is sufficient. If you showed the average person two buttons, one labeled "search iPhone models for sale" and the other "search iPhone listings for sale", would they be able to clearly understand the difference without additional context? Perhaps adding the word "individual" before "listings" helps with the distinction, but it seems a bit verbose. I'm also not sure if the term "listing" is still prevalently used outside of specific niches such as real estate.

Comment: The word that comes to my mind, though I’m uncertain whether it’s what you’re looking for, is “range”.  A search for the “range of iphones” would yield the list of iphone models, colours, capacities, etc - similar to your “class”.

Comment: *fungibility/non-fungibility* involves some of these concepts, specifically whether something is identical and substitutable or not. The question is a bit vague, but it sounds like you want a word for something which is fungible and something which is non-fungible.

Comment: With plants, it's species and specimens.

Comment: The problem is that Apple and other retailers also sell used ("certified refurbished") iPhones — from inventory, not "one off." You get an instance, but you don't know which one.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem of wordiness, but it seems like you're looking to describe the difference between consumer-to-consumer sales and business-to-consumer sales.

Comment: Even though the question is clear and carefully written, it leaves one wondering what is the context in which you want to use the terms you are seeking. If the context is some kind of a theoretical analysis of e-commerce, then sticking with *class* and *instance* is probably the best (if one is not sure whether one's audience is familiar with the terms, one can explain them at their first occurrence). If the context is more colloquial, one may need to resort to something longer like 'this particular item'.

Answer (score 1):

You can only ever buy an instance of a product (unless you buy the copyright/IP). The class or category of the item is abstract and not something you can obtain in a shop.

The intrinsic difference in your example between Amazon and eBay is about the state of the instance: new, used, refurbished or factory reject.

Generally, the words you would use for the class/instance of objects would depend on the field:

- Model vs car/phone/computer/plane
- Variety vs plant/specimen
- Breed vs dog/cat/specimen
- Species vs animal/specimen

Comment: Specifically, the state of the instance on Amazon is assumed to be "pristine" and therefore all instances are considered fungible, whereas on eBay no assumptions are made about the state, and therefore the state is explicitly considered in the buying process, rendering different instances non-fungible.

Comment: Yet "poison ivy is a plant" is just as valid as "poison ivy is a variety of plant", even though I'm not talking about a specific instance of it.

Comment: "Poison ivy" is a category, not a specimen. "Plant" is also a category.